# HLS (.m3u8) video not playing with textTracks in React native video iOS

Tags: react-native, video, m3u8

HLS (.m3u8) video not playing with textTracks in React native video package iOS and In android the video is playing but textTracks is not displaying while playing the video

If we remove the textTracks HLS (.m3u8) video is playing in react native video iOS

```
 <Video
            onEnd={this.onEnd}
            onLoad={this.onLoad}
            onLoadStart={this.onLoadStart}
            onProgress={this.onProgress}
            paused={this.state.paused}
            ref={this.player}
            resizeMode={this.state.screenType}
            onFullScreen={this.state.isFullScreen}
            rate={this.state.playbackSpeedValue}
            reportBandwidth
            onBandwidthUpdate={this.onBandwidthUpdate}
            source={{
              uri: this.state.activeVideo,
             }}
            
            selectedVideoTrack={{
              type: "resolution",
              value: 480
            }}
            style={(screenVal == false) ? styles.mediaPlayer : styles.mediaPlayer}
            volume={this.state.sliderValue}
            selectedTextTrack={{
              type: this.state.captionsType,
              value: 0,
            }}


            textTracks={[
              {
                index: 0,
                title: "English CC",
                language: "en-us",
                type: TextTrackType.VTT, // "text/vtt"
                uri: 'https://d2tvoqe2tsxhc6.cloudfront.net/Video1-testsample64.vtt'
              },

            ]}


          />
```

Comment: you got the solution?
I'm able to see the subtitles for mp4 videos but m3u8 with textTracks not even working

Comment: I'm assuming it has to do with the progress and duration, as they're fundamentally different.

Comment: As per the documentation, you cannot display tracks for the HLS playlist :
"On iOS, sidecar text tracks are only supported for individual files, not HLS playlists. For HLS, you should include the text tracks as part of the playlist.
"

https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/blob/v6.0.0-alpha.8/API.md#texttracks